# Twitter app invalid URL

Tags: twitter

I am hosting a development version of a site, let's call it:

```
http://localhost/mysite
```

I am trying to create a twitter app on

```
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
```

However, the URL of

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php
```

or the URL of

```
htpp://127.0.0.1/mysite/index.php
```

are not accepted. The error is:

```
Not a valid URL format
```

Is there a solution for my problem? I was searching for a solution, but, apparently twitter API has a new version and all the solutions I have found are older than the API's new version. Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are testing it through emulator or bluestack just change the 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2

otherwiset the url(27.0.0.1/mysite/index.php ) is good. If you faced the problem then first check your localhost is working or not and you used the android.permission.internet in your manifest.

Comment: I do not know why, but http://127.0.0.1/mysite/index.php solved the problem. I could swear that I was testing with that too.

Comment: I do not know how, but it seems that the issue was solved. The best we can do is that you edit your answer to reflect how calid URLs look like and I will accept it so this post will help others in the future.

Comment: Twitter now requires your site to be a https site